# In a Twilio outbound call, how detect when the other party answered the call?

Tags: javascript, events, twilio

I am using Twilio Client for JavaScript version 1.4.

When using this client-side library for making calls in Chrome browser, is there anyway to receieve an event to detect call answered state?

So far I have been able to only detect ringing and in-progress events but my problem is that in-progress fires even before the other party answers the call.

All my searches had returned no useful result and the existing documentation is very poor. I would like to know especially how to use enableRingingState if it is related to client-side events. And for now I don't want to use server-side event pushed to client as I beleive the twilio JavaScript SDK should have the ability to detect those events in the client-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I understand that you believe that the JavaScript SDK should be able to detect the phone being answered. It's just that currently it can't.

This is a feature that the team are considering. In the meantime, it is recommended to use the call status callback webhooks and push those events to the client side.

Comment: Thank you very much, it is good to know clearly it is not supported now, so we can look into other solutions.

Comment: Any update to this?

Comment: I'm afraid I no longer work for Twilio and haven't kept up with this SDK. I'd recommend checking the documentation to see if this is an option now.